# How to apply lambda function to specific column based on the values in the adjacent column

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, lambda, apply

I am trying a apply a lambda function to a pandas data frame. My question is how can I apply a lambda function to column a based on value in column b using if statement.

```
A B C
2 5 7
4 5 9
6 7 9
```

```
df['B'].apply(lambda x: x+3 if x<(#the value in column C) else x)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `apply` *on the dataframe, with `axis=1`*, instead of on the `B` column:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x['B']+3 if x['B']<x['C'] else x['B'], axis=1)
0     8
1     8
2    10
dtype: int64
```

But, a **much** more efficient (faster) way would be to do this:

```
>>> df['B'] + df['B'].lt(df['C']) * 3
0     8
1     8
2    10
dtype: int64
```

Comment: perfect exactly what I was looking for. thank you!